# In Unity, how can I get the coordinates of the position of this object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

In Unity

When 3d objects are placed in reality using , how can I get the coordinates of the position of this object?

Comment: This question needs some clarification. When you say "placed in reality", what do you mean? This is tagged ARCore, so I would assume you're creating some AR application? What coordinates are you looking for? Of course there is the standard `transform.position` which you could query for you're object's "World" position, but this is in-engine only. If you need some position with respect to the real (i.e. non-virtual) world, you'd need to define a bit more clearly what your setup looks like.

Comment: You might want to look at `transform.position` as well as `transform.localPosition`. The former is absolute in the world. The later is relative to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unclear question, be more precise.

If you want to move the object, then these videos might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNtOcDryKv4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZEu_I-ido4

If you want to see the coordinates for your object, then click on the "transform" tab.

If you want to set coordinates of an object in script, then look here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/935069/how-do-i-set-an-objects-coordinates-in-scripts.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).